# Video Play on hover, performance issues, return to background image of the video

Tags: html, jquery, css

I want to make a website portfolio where I play videos on mouse over. I did it for the performance because if I put them on autoplay loop my pc is burning.
Everything is working fine, but when I put more videos on the page the **cpu and memory ussage is very high**. I think the problem is that the video goes to pause and the page has to save the current time position of the video when I click away.

**I want to stop the video, not pause it and go back to the background image,to see if the performance go up.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="script.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center ">
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
      <video class="myvideos loop muted preload="none" height="300" width="500"">
      <source src="under.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="under.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video></div>
<div class="col">    
      <video class="myvideos loop muted preload="none" height="300" width="500"">
      <source src="under.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="under.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video></div>
<div class="col">    
      <video class="myvideos loop muted preload="none" height="300" width="500"">
      <source src="under.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="under.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video></div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".myvideos").on("mouseover", function(event) {
    this.play();

  }).on('mouseout', function(event) {
    this.pause();

  });
})
```

```css
.myvideos {
  background: url('underpass4.jpg') no-repeat;

}
.row{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
```

Comment: I've tried this,same performance issue.
.on('mouseout', function(event) {
    this.pause();
    this.currentTime = 0;

Comment: Maybe if i find a condition to play only one video at time.

Comment: I think about using a video carousel to increase performance.